# Doctrine compare two objects

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I need to compare two objects in doctrine. I have customer repository and entity. This is my code,

```
 public function index(CarAdRepository $carAdRepository, CustomerRepository $customerRepository): Response {
        $cus = $customerRepository->findAll();
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->setTitle('Mr');
        $customer->setName('aaa');
        $customer->setLastName('bbb');
        if($customer == $cus[0]){
            echo 'ddd';
        }else{
            echo 'no';
        }
    }
```

in my table I have this values,

[image]

But I always get no. It would be great if someone can help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doctrine implements `IdentityMap` pattern that ensures that you're always receiving **same** object for same database row, but *only if it was loaded from identity map*.

In your case you're comparing some arbitrary object with entity fetched from database using PHP comparison operator. In other words you're checking if 2 objects are equal, but there is no such built-in functionality in PHP.

You have to implement objects comparison function by yourself to achieve your goal because actual comparison logic may vary.

**UPDATE:**
Simplest example of comparison in your case is property-by-property comparison:

```
private function compare(Customer $a, Customer $b)
{
    return $a->getTitle() === $b->getTitle() &&
        $a->getName() === $b->getName() &&
        $a->getLastName() === $b->getLastName();
}
```

It also may be worth to move this method directly into `Customer` entity with name like `isEqual()`.

It is also possible to implement more generic approach by using [reflection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), but it may bring certain level of complexity in a case if some non-trivial comparison will need to be involved.

Comment: thanks so much but is there an example I can view?. Sorry I'm bit new to this :(